# Imprimir a url absoluta em uma view com AspNetCore

Tags: asp.net-core

Estou começando a trabalhar com o AspNetCore, e estou tendo dificuldades para conseguir imprimir a url absoluta do meu projeto. Venho do PHP e procuro algo parecido com o código abaixo, escrito em PHP:

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

Alguma idéia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que separar o host e o path em sua View, segue o código.

```
@Context.Request.Host@Context.Request.Path
```